# Cucumber-JUnit control parallel tests with tags

Tags: junit, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Recently I created a framework with **Cucumber-JUnit** where I am able to execute Scenarios in parallel (For now keeping one scenario per feature) without any issue.

Now I have a situation where **some of the features has to run in parallel and some in sequence**.

Is there any way that we can control with tags or any other configuration to choose which has to run in parallel or sequence?

Let me put some overview how it is currently

Parallel and its thread size controlled as per cucumber official documentation - Maven surefire

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
   <configuration>
       <parallel>methods</parallel>
       <threadCount>${threadSize}</threadCount>
       <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**CucumberRunner:**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = {"com.tests.binding.steps"},
        tags = "@regression"
)
public class RunCucumberFeatures {

}
```

command using to run tests

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="${toExecute} and not (@smoke)" -DthreadCount=${ThreadSize} -Dcucumber.execution.dry-run="false"
```

For **`toExecute`** parameter - we pass multiple tags like `@customerClaim or @employeeClaim`

Now, In my case  features with tags **@employeeClaim should execute in parallel** and tags with **@customerClaim should execute in sequence**.

Is it possible with current design or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way that we can control with tags or any other configuration to choose which has to run in parallel or sequence?

Not with `cucumber-junit` and JUnit 4. However with JUnit 5 you can use the `cucumber-junit-platform-engine` and use JUnit 5s support for exclusive resources.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine

> To synchronize a scenario on a specific resource, the scenario must be tagged and this tag mapped to a lock for the specific resource. A resource is identified by an arbitrary string and can be either locked with a read-write-lock, or a read-lock.
>
> For example, the following tags:

```
Feature: Exclusive resources

   @reads-and-writes-system-properties
   Scenario: first example
      Given this reads and writes system properties
      When it is executed
      Then it will not be executed concurrently with the second example

   @reads-system-properties
   Scenario: second example
      Given this reads system properties
      When it is executed
      Then it will not be executed concurrently with the first example
```

> with this configuration:

```
cucumber.execution.exclusive-resources.reads-and-writes-system-properties.read-write=java.lang.System.properties
cucumber.execution.exclusive-resources.reads-system-properties.read=java.lang.System.properties
```

> when executing the first scenario tagged with @reads-and-writes-system-properties will lock the java.lang.System.properties resource with a read-write lock and will not be concurrently executed with the second scenario that locks the same resource with a read lock.
>
> Note: The @ from the tag is not included in the property name. Note: For canonical resource names see junit5/Resources.java

So by making an exclusive resource for `@customerClaim` you can prevent these scenarios from running in parallel. However to the best of my knowledge JUnit 5 makes no guarantees made about the order of execution so they should still be independent from each other.

Comment: the tags that I mention `@customerClaim or @employeeClaim` are feature tags but not scenario. All my scenarios are independent only. But some feature files has to execute in sequence.

Comment: Tags on a feature are applied to all scenarios in that feature. If your scenarios are independent the order in which they are executed should not matter. It sounds like your scenarios are not independent.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if we could select which tests to run in parallel only by tags. I will be fighting with microservices very soon and I would like most of my tests to run in parallel to save time. So far I have been testing a monolith and my framework is already done with multiple .feature files and tags configured to run on different environments. So if there is an easy way to configure which tests to run in parallel and the rest in sequence using tags - it would be nice to know.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).